# Checkout Finland PSP API Java implementation

Tags: java, checkout

Am trying to integrate finland's checkout api in my project. It always gives me 401 (i.e., as per API my Hmac calculation failed).
Her is the link to api where they calculated Hmac using nodejs and php. 
https://checkoutfinland.github.io/psp-api/#/examples

Can anyone help me where am going wron in my java code. Here is my code:

```
// Make sure all check-out headers are in alphabetical order and
    // all header keys must be in lower case
    // if request contains body - it should be valid JSON and content-type header should be included
    Map<String, String> headersMap = new TreeMap<>();
    headersMap.put("checkout-account", "375917");
    headersMap.put("checkout-algorithm", "sha256");
    headersMap.put("checkout-method", "POST");
    headersMap.put("checkout-nonce", String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));  // unique identifier for this request
    headersMap.put("checkout-timestamp", ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT )); // ISO 8601 format date time

    /**
     * All API calls need to be signed using HMAC and SHA-256 or SHA-512
     */
    String headers[] = new String[headersMap.size()];

    int index = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> headersEntry: headersMap.entrySet()){
        headers[index++] = headersEntry.getKey()+":"+headersEntry.getValue();
    }

    Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
    requestBody.put("stamp", "29858472952");
    requestBody.put("reference", "9187445");
    requestBody.put("amount", 1500);
    requestBody.put("currency", "EUR");
    requestBody.put("language", "FI");
    List<List<Map<String, Object>>> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> item = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> itemObj = new HashMap<>();
    itemObj.put("unitPrice", 1500);
    itemObj.put("units",1);
    itemObj.put("vatPercentage", 5);
    itemObj.put("productCode", "#1234");
    itemObj.put("deliveryDate", "2018-09-01");
    item.add(itemObj);
    itemsList.add(item);
    requestBody.put("items", itemsList);
    Map<String, Object> customer = new HashMap<>();
    customer.put("email", "test.customer@example.com");
    requestBody.put("customer", customer);
    Map<String, Object> redirectUrls = new HashMap<>();
    redirectUrls.put("success","example.com");
    redirectUrls.put("cancel","example.com");
    requestBody.put("redirectUrls",redirectUrls);

    String body = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(requestBody);

    String data = String.join("\n", ArrayUtils.addAll(headers, body));

    String hmacSha256Hash = calculateHmacSha256("SAIPPUAKAUPPIAS", data);

    if(hmacSha256Hash != null){
        headersMap.put("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headersMap.put("signature", hmacSha256Hash);

        // Make network call checkout api
     }
```

Hmac Calculation method:

```
private String calculateHmacSha256(String key, String data){
    String resultHash = null;
    try {
        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"),"HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

        resultHash = Hex.encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error calculating HmacSHA256 hash for data data"+  e);
    }

    return resultHash;
}
```

I implemented it identical to the one which they have in the examples.

Comment: 401 is unauthorized...

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output suggests your SHA256 HMAC _calculation_ is working. (That's not to say that you may not have misused the signing...) I'd concentrate elsewhere as per the other comment.

Comment: @brso05 Yeah 401 is unauthorized correct. In the API it is given that => 401 Unauthorized HMAC calculation failed or Merchant has no access to this feature. As am passing test merchant credentials they are correct.

Comment: You don't says what endpoint you are invoking, but clearly this is unauthorized for this user. I see this "Please note that not all payment methods support testing, so only the payment methods that support testing payments are enabled for these credentials." But it is unclear whether this has come into play yet.

Comment: I tried in postman hitting their API with hardcoded values given in this example ( https://checkoutfinland.github.io/psp-api/#/examples). It throws Signature mismatch error. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.